# I need help figuring out a sticky footer

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

Finally made the leap to `<div>`s as opposed to a table layout. I'm ready to pull my hair out.

I hope this helps. I'm shooting for [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ncenyeemiikwcu/draftblue.png).

So it's easier to explain: [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbl3fnywemo7h1p/draftbluepanels.png)

I have no trouble getting the blue, pink and yellow boxes to work properly. I can even get the green one at the bottom by using a sticky footer. But the red box messes everything up for me, because the top of it is higher than the yellow box. I'd love to know how to fix this.

Just some advice on how to make this happen would be appreciated more than I can put into words.

Comment: what are the red and blue boxes for?

Comment: You need to post some CSS and HTML so we can see what's going on. I also ditto the red and blue box question...

Comment: The red and blue boxes are a dark grey pattern repeated. The rest of the background is a dark blue. I added them to create depth (I considered doing it without, but I think it looks better, and it is driving me crazy I can't figure it out).

Comment: position relative, z-index: 1000, is that the problem ?

Comment: Here is a sample of what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/WMV7P/6/  I can put a div behind the content to stretch the color down, I just can't figure out how to keep the large background behind the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is this the layout you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/GzPnL/

You can use `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;` in your css.

Comment: That's great, it definitely gives the shape. But once the content is longer than the page, the bottom stays where it was. Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/GzPnL/1/

Comment: To let the footer stay where it is, even with longer content, you need to give the footer the property `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`

I hope this solves your problem http://jsfiddle.net/GzPnL/2/

Comment: That keeps it at the bottom of the page, but I want it below the bottom of the content.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WMV7P/7/embedded/result/ - Playing around with the margins and padding, I've almost got what I need. The problem now is that I can't keep a background color when the content is shorter than the screen. How can I stretch the color to the bottom?

Comment: I solved my problem! http://jsfiddle.net/WMV7P/7/light/ By playing around with margins, padding and z-index, I got what I wanted. Thank you for your help!